# Obfuscating Rails app on MRI Ruby / JRuby for a enterprise customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, obfuscation

For a enterprise customer, who will be running our Rails app on their servers, we don't want to give them the source code of a Rails app.

Is it possible, using MRI Ruby or even JRuby, to:

1. Obfuscate the source code
2. In case of JRuby, make the Rails app into a .jar/.war (so it's obfuscated and byte-code)
3. In case of MRI Ruby, package the Rails app into an EXE

Any thoughts on if this is possible?

Comment: Since you are selling software to an enterprise/corporate customer, I expect you have a lawyer who's helping you with your contract and such. Discuss your copyrights, and whether you're working in a "Work-for-hire" situation. Copyright laws plus the legal agreements in the contract can negate the need for any sort of code obfuscation. It's a sign of the times when we have to have a lawyer in our pockets, but they can do a wonderful job of giving you a warm-fuzzy feeling when dealing with this stuff. Just a suggestion.

Comment: If this is X to do Y, here's Y: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99553/can-you-distribute-a-ruby-on-rails-application-without-source?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've used [RubyEncoder](http://rubyencoder.com/). it is crossplatform and very flexible. if i remember correctly it works only with MRI.
check if it fits your needs.