# Ruby & Rails: code guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zend-guard

Is there some sort of "Zend code guard" for rails applications ?

Sultan

Comment: Oh, its like an obfuscator... http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/faq - and no idea, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been covered before, so question may end getting closed as a dupe.

[Can you Distribute a Ruby on Rails Application without Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99553/can-you-distribute-a-ruby-on-rails-application-without-source)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [JRuby](http://jruby.org/), you can then use the [warbler](http://rubygems.org/gems/warbler) gem to package your rails application into a war.

Please note that a war-file is easily inspected, so it offers no real protection; but is a start.