# Create Ruby/Rake executable

Tags: ruby, compilation, rake, binaryfiles, packaging

Is there any way to create executable binaries from Ruby/Rake task?

I have simple FileUtil tool written in ruby and I'd like to package it somehow into script that can be run or OSX, Linux or Windows. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is an interpreted language and not a compiled one like C or Java. Then answering your question is not so easy.

But there are some tools that permit you to protect your source code (encrypting) and creating some packages that are runnable cross platform (but in this case you should ever resolve any dependency).

This question covers pretty good how you can distribuite your code without (or encrypting) your source code: [Can you Distribute a Ruby on Rails Application without Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99553/can-you-distribute-a-ruby-on-rails-application-without-source)

Other useful tools that I have founded in these moments:
- Compiling a rake https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler
- Debian (.deb) packaging http://crohr.me/pkgr/