# Deploying a Rails app offline and with all dependencies intact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, offline

My goal is to deploy an existing Rails app on a machine. Oh, and the machine is on a handful of terminals in a remote community in the north of Australia. Oh, and I can't rely on there being Internet access for troubleshooting or admin purposes.

I'd like to package the app with a fresh copy of Rails and all of the apps dependencies (some of which must be built natively) so that the server can be run and a browser used as the front-end. The remote machines are modern Macs, and I should be able to replicate the configuration for testing here.

I've spotted some projects like Locomotive and Joyent Slingshot, as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711/options-for-distribution-of-an-offline-ruby-on-rails-application), but both of those projects seem to have been abandoned, and [this link](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html) is Windows-specific.

Does anyone have any guidance as to what the modern way of doing this is? A community project thanks you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming those remove machines have Ruby available, you could use Bundler to freeze all your gems in your project:

```
bundle package
```

Read more at [getbundler.com](http://gembundler.com/)

Comment: Does Bundler actually wrap up prebuilt C extensions and the like? It seems to me that it just takes a snapshot of your Gem configuration so that you can reproduce it on the remote machine. Ideally I'd like everything to be in the package, ready to run the Rails server.